# How do i create nested models using Backbone.Js

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, backbone.js, router

I am trying to create a Task application with Backbone.Js. Task is a model represented on server side as below

```
Task

  TaskName (string)

  SubTasks (List<Task>)

  Tasks  (List<UserTask>)
```

- How do i declare a model that is nested like **Task** (see `SubTasks`) here.
- How **should**  / can i display a data that could be n-level nested on a single view(if it is optimal) does any pattern exist for such a problem.( certainly treeview isn't that friendly for something like this, Indentation can  aid in nesting but upto a certain level only & we are limited by screen sizes of browsers, desktop, mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this link can solve your problem http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested.

An alternative could be the backbone relational library https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

Cheers,
Fabrizio